# I am winding a large induction coil but ran out of wire and need to solder or connect more wire to the existing wraps, how best to do this?

Tags: coil, induction, winding

I'm winding a 6" coil with 16ga magnet wire.  I want about 1600 turns but ran out of wire.  What is best way to add more wire w/o creating a problem at the join, such as over-heating or creating a bump at the join?

As an aside, I would prefer to just buy a large coil of 16ga magnet wire so that I wouldnt have to wind it myself.  But any coils I find do not have a center hole large enough to put a 1.5" iron core inside.

Comment: bring the junction to the outside of the coil, similar to a center tapped transformer

Comment: If you have a suitable coil former, you can try asking at an armature winding's or transformer manufacturer. (The last one I knew closed two decades ago.)

Comment: Would it be best or okay to use silver solder or can i just heat the junction and fuse the two copper ends together at the joint?